# To retrieve every iteration/version of component published

Tags: core-service, 2011-sp1

We have a requirement to generate a report on every iteration/version of component published.

For example, if a component published 3 times within the requested date range, then all 3 versions has be retrieved and show them in a report.

It seems like we can get this information  by querying WFL_PROCESS_HISTORIES table.

Could you please let me know how to get this data using core services or there is any other approach to generate this kind of report?.

We are using 2011 SP1 version.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: One thing to note, WFL_PROCESS_HISTORIES will have details of publish only if it is done through workflow. If that is not the case always that you publish outside the workflow also then please revisit your question.

Comment: Hiren, At this point of time, we are trying to generate a report on workflow publish items. So trying to see how to to get the old published versions of a component....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to display information regarding when an item was published, which version etc. 
By default, Tridion does not keep track of historical publish data and keeps overriding the publish information and keeps track of only the last published transaction for any given item.

If you want to capture details of which item version to which target type, by whom, when etc. you have to write event system code to subscribe to the

```
EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<PublishTransaction, SaveEventArgs>(OnPublishStatus_Initiated, EventPhases.Initiated);
```

to capture the information. You can get all the information that you are looking for if you subscribe to this event and then capture it from the publish transaction. 
We had similar requirement and we wrote event system code which triggers on publish to capture the relevant information and keep it in a custom DB. We have also written a GUI extension to display the information which allows the user to select an item and then with our GUI extension we display the information that we captured for the item which includes which version which target, when, by whom, whether the transaction was successful or not.

Once you capture the information, you can use it as you wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. But in Tridion CME UI, under Workflow management there is process histories section. Under this section we can see all the components(all versions) published by the authors. This data shows that Tridion stores this info in a table and I'm trying to see how to retrieve data from this table and generate a custom report to business.

Answer (score 1):

As Vipin says, Tridion does not store this information out of the box.

As well as a custom database, you could also consider writing this information to the Component's/Page's Application Data (using Event System code) and then writing a tool to retrieve this (via the Core Service).

You will need to be aware of anyone [purging old versions of content items](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D51E5BE8-1ADC-4089-BABF-CAF0FA6A70E1) as part of the normal Tridion maintenance, as this may invalidate your versioning information.

Depending on the reasons for storing this information (legal, etc.), you may want to consider a dedicated archiving tool - such as [Archive Manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Archive%20Manager%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2F36B0FD-23D1-425A-98FA-1C03D5812D36) or [PageFreezer](https://www.pagefreezer.com/).